As of May 2024, does the US state of Georgia prohibit "water to be available to you while you wait in line to vote in an election"?
On 19 May 2024 at Morehouse College, Joe Biden said:

But let’s be clear what happens to you and your family when old ghosts in new garments seize power, extremists come for the freedoms you thought belonged to you and everyone.
Today in Georgia, they won’t allow water to be available to you while you wait in line to vote in an election.  What in the hell is that all about?  (Applause.) I’m serious.  Think about it.


Deleted lots of comments that are not about clarifying the question.

Welcome to HNQ users. Please read our Welcome to Skeptics before answering or commenting.

Mr Biden is no doubt aware that Treating is a crime in lots of countries.

@Richard which requires "corrupt intent", not just the action of giving food or drink.

@Caleth - Indeed. As I put in my (alas deleted) answer, in the UK if you announced that you're from a particular party and gave someone free water while they wait in line at the polling booth, you'd be promptly arrested. If you just tell them that you're a kindly person giving out water, you'll be absolutely fine. It's the intent to corrupt that's the issue, not the giving out of water.

@Richard a bit more than that. The UKIP sausage rolls guy was asked to visit a police station but not arrested.

@Caleth - Yes. He hid behind the fact that this was 'ordinary hospitality' at a community event, not something out of the ordinary such as giving away free water to people standing in a queue.

@Richard are you being sarcastic? He didn't "hide behind" it being ordinary hospitality. It doesn't amount to a crime when it is ordinary hospitality

Giving water directly is forbidden, self-service is allowed.
This was also covered by Politifact as well as several news sources, such as Business Insider, referring to the Election Integrity Act, more specifically SB202 which amended the law in August 2022.
Directly from the document itself:

(a) No person shall solicit votes in any manner or by any means or
method, nor shall any person distribute or display any campaign
material, nor shall any person give, offer to give, or participate
in the giving of any money or gifts, including, but not limited to,
food and drink, to an elector, nor shall any person solicit
signatures for any petition, nor shall any person, other than election
officials discharging their duties, establish or set up any tables or
booths on any day in which ballots are being cast:
(1) Within 150 feet of the outer edge of any building within which a polling place is established;
(2) Within any polling place; or
(3) Within 25 feet of any voter standing in line to vote at any polling place. These restrictions shall not apply to conduct occurring in private offices or areas which cannot be seen or heard by such electors.

Of note, it is possible to make water available as long as it's self-service (props to @LegionMammal978 for the find):

(e) This Code section shall not be construed to prohibit a poll
officer from [...] making available self-service water from an
unattended receptacle to an elector waiting in line to vote.


Deleted obsolete comments and ones not related to improving the answer. Your political opinions are not welcome here.

Note that these sources are dated 2021-2022. There were changes in 2023 [and talk of further legal challenges].

@Oddthinking You deleted my current (as of the past few days) GA government and Atlanta news web sites that provided specifics. How are these opinions? These addressed how the law will be enforced and the speculation that this law is for voter suppression. Isn't that the point of improving the answer.

Sometimes "self-service" involves leaving the voting line, which people are reluctant to do in case they give up their place.

@DogBoy37: You made pseudo-answer comments on the main question. If you want to post an answer, please use the answer box, where it can be voted on, edited and accepted.
